# Update Widget For Night Mode

Tags: android, android-widget, android-night-mode

I have made a simple note Widget in android. I added a night mode feature in it where the widget color will go from red during the day to black at night. I used this code to make the app change the widget based on time of day:

```
    // Find Night Mode Automatically//
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);

    // Checks Whether app Is In Night Mode Or Not//
    int currentNightMode = context.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;

    // Checks All Scenarios//
    switch (currentNightMode) {

        // Night Mode Is Not Active, We're In Day Time//
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO: {

            // Instantiate Variable RemoteViews remoteViews / Directs Activity To GUI//
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.note_widget_ui);

            // Initiate viewText Method//
            viewText(context, remoteViews);

            // Kill Code//
            break;
        }

        // Night Mode Is Active, We're At Night!//
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES: {

            // Instantiate Variable RemoteViews remoteViews / Directs Activity To GUI//
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.note_widget_night_ui);

            // Initiate viewText Method//
            viewText(context, remoteViews);

            // Kill Code//
            break;
        }

        // We Don't Know What Mode We're In, Assume Notnight//
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED: {

            // Instantiate Variable RemoteViews remoteViews / Directs Activity To GUI//
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.note_widget_ui);

            // Initiate viewText Method//
            viewText(context, remoteViews);

            // Kill Code//
            break;
        }
    }
```

How do I use this code to make the widget update its color once night mode comes on. Another example of this is nova launcher and the google bar widget. It switches once night mode is activated by android. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: try to take a look at this [one](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-daynight-theme-example-using-appcompat-v23-2/)

Comment: Changing the day night mode for my activity is fine. Its updating the widget on my homescreen to go from red to black thats the problem. I don't know how to tell the widget to update it by itself once night or day comes

Comment: have you maded a color xml and a public style class?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work and uses a lot of what you were doing. My demo shows the day-night theme working on widgets. :) There is a problem, the app must be running in order to determine what mode is on. But if it's about not doing auto then works all the time https://github.com/juanmendez/android-styling-recipes/tree/02.dayNightTheme+Widget

That's half an answer. This is a full answer to it. I wrote a library when used with the application then it requires certain dependencies which you need to include. Then it makes use of your dependencies and allows your WidgetProvider to update widgets to a day or night theme. https://github.com/juanmendez/LightThemeScheduler